# Javascript - duplicate listeners if callback is defined in prototype and then bound

Tags: javascript, callback, bind, observable

Basically, I have implemented an observable object and another class (i.e. Subscriber) which has a callback function in its prototype.

In the callback, I want to do something with the class's properties, therefore, the this has to be set correctly.  Here's an example.

```
Subscriber = function() {
    this.pararmA = 1;
}

Subscriber.prototype.OnValueChanged = function(value){
    alert(this.paramA + value);
}
```

In my observable, listener has to be unique (i.e. same listener is not allowed to be added into the subscriber list more than once).  Now below is the test.

```
var a = Observable(0);
var b = new Subscriber();

a.AddListener(b.OnValueChanged.bind(b));
a.AddListener(b.OnValueChanged.bind(b));

a(1);
a(2);
```

What I expected is I see an alert of 2 and 3 once but instead I saw an alert of 2 and 3 twice due to the 1st b.OnValueChanged.bind(b) is "identical" to the 2nd b.OnValueChanged.bind(b)

If I add the following code to the previous block of code:

```
var c = b.OnValueChanged.bind(b);
var d = b.OnValueChanged.bind(b);

alert( c == d );
```

I will get a popup saying "false"

So I was thinking to put all the callbacks into the class instead of the prototype:

i.e.

```
Subscriber = function() {
    this.pararmA = 1;

    this.OnValueChanbed = function(value){
        alert(this.paramA + value);
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Then in the code just use the callback as it is:

```
var a = Observable(0);
var b = new Subscriber();

a.AddListener(b.OnValueChanged);
a.AddListener(b.OnValueChanged);
```

This solution seems ok but then every object with callbacks will have a copy of the callback functions (because using prototype should reduce memory consumption)

Comment: By "What I expected is I see an alert of 2 and 3 once but instead I saw an alert of 2 and 3 twice due to the 1st b."

Do you mean 1 and 2 right? Those are parameters passed to a(1) and a(2)

Comment: it's 2 and 3 due to in my example the OnValueChanged callback will add this.paramA to the value where this.paramA is a constant 1.